# node-restful GET query string for querying a sub-entity

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

Using Node + Express + Mongoose + node-restful

https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful

The problem i am facing is filtering sub-entity data.

Model Schema is defined as follows for node-restful

```
//Schema
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: { type: 'String', required: true },
    content: { type: 'String', required: true },
    tags: [{ name : {type: 'String'} }]

});
```

When i perform a get request this is what i get
which is correct as i have two records only.

http://localhost:3000/api/post

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5529866ae1ad43bd95d6b335",
        "title": "amazon My Post",
        "content": "dasdd This is a post with some tags",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "amazon"
            },
            {
                "name": "tracking"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "55298674e1ad43bd95d6b336",
        "title": "flipkart My Post",
        "content": "dasdjkjfkajd This is a post with some tags",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "flipkart"
            },
            {
                "name": "tracking"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

I want to perform something like this 
http://localhost:3000/api/post/?tags.name=amazon

it should return me only one record, the one which has its tag.name as "amazon"

this works fine if i fire db.getCollection('posts').find({ "tags.name" : "amazon"}) on mongodb, how do i get this to work with node-restful

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5529866ae1ad43bd95d6b335",
        "title": "amazon My Post",
        "content": "dasdd This is a post with some tags",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "amazon"
            },
            {
                "name": "tracking"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

instead its returning me all the results.

where am i going wrong.

Is there a better way to store tags in mongo db

My code is as follows

**server.js**

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/NodeMongo');

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Enable CORS
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.use('/api',require('./routes/api'));

// Start Server
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Api is running on port 3000');
```

**api.js**

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

Post.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);
Post.register(router, '/post');

module.exports = router;
```

**post.js**

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

//Schema
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: { type: 'String', required: true },
    content: { type: 'String', required: true },
    tags: [{ name : {type: 'String'} }]

});


//Return model 
module.exports = restful.model('Posts', postSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you represented tags is fine, though if you only have one property on the tag, why not just an array of strings?

Looking at github, I see that node-restful uses a django like notation for filtering. Did you try?

```
?tags.name__eq=amazon
```

or

```
?tags%20name__eq=amazon
```

If it doesn't work, then perhaps the library doesn't support addressing nested properties as key paths.

It would probably be pretty easy for you to add the capability yourself.

It will probably also work as is, if you use an array of strings to represent tags in your model.

Sooner or later though, if the library has this limitation, you'll come across this situation again and won't be able to work around it by changing your model.

Comment: Look at the source and see whether key paths are supported, but I'm thinking they are not. Fork the project and fix it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

There are [Populating a sub-entity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-restful#populating-a-sub-entity) in node-restful, you can try that way

Answer (score 0):

The "find" method returns a Promise, try to insert a "await" to return the result only then the Promise was resolved.

```
await db.getCollection('posts').find({ "tags.name" : "amazon"})
```